# Remove gem from default gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

When using `rails new`, the following gems are automatically included in a Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
```

I'm not a huge fan of SASS, and I strongly dislike Coffeescript, and it's getting annoying having .scss and .js.coffee files in every new project.

How can I remove these gems from `rails new` so that they won't be included by default in every new project?

Thanks for any responses in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: You can always create your own `template.rb` and pass that into `rails new` using the `--template` or `-m` option. [RailsWizard](http://railswizard.org/) will even generate a template for you.

Let me also say that the default template doesn't generates any `.scss` or `.coffee` files, but it is a little annoying that the gems are bundled automatically. Mostly, though, you could ignore that they're installed--just remove those two lines from your `Gemfile`.